# Apollo Server Lambda - any practical example about serverless

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, graphql, apollo

I have been tring to implement a graphql application on aws for a while. I am researching the ways to implement graphql on serverless. I have checked couple of examples on how people implements apollo server on lambda.

My understanding that people use one lambda as their gateway. So one lambda handles queries and mutations. It didn’t seem quite right to me.

The second solution i am thinking is use an ec2 server as gateway, however this time i lose the power of cognito. (Or i couldnt find anyway to work with cognito and ec2)

I dont want to use appsync. I am just looking for a way around.

The question is apollo server implementation correct ? Is there any other way or a good example about this?

Answer (score 1):

Let say your requirements can be list out as:

- GraphQL
- AWS and cognito

I suggest using [Hasura](https://hasura.io/). That's a good candidate to boost your development process drastically. Hasura communication is great also.